# Why margin of child div doesn't collapse with parent margin div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn when margins are collapsing.

I followed this article: [What’s the Deal with Margin Collapse?](https://jonathan-harrell.com/whats-the-deal-with-margin-collapse/) and still don't understand why the following margins don't collapse.

Which rule did I break?

```css
.container1 {
    background-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    margin-top: 10em;
}
.container2 {
    background-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: purple;
    margin-top: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
    <div class="container2">
        aaaaa
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because of the border `The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.` https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) - The Official Difinition](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#collapsing-margins) from W3.ORG, they said:

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> ....
>
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and **no border separate them**
>
> ...

In your case, try to remove the `border-style: solid;` like this:

```
    .container1 {
        background-color: red;
        border-color: black;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .container2 {
        background-color: green;
        border-color: purple;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

The ***collapsed margin*** will happen.